# Properties of a recursively-defined sequence using induction

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

This is a homework problem. Not expecting the solution, just a nudge in the right direction!

$N$ is a function defined inductively as follows:

$$N(1) = N(2) = N(3) = 1$$

$$N(n) = N(n−1) + N(n−3) \quad \text{for } n > 3.$$

> **a.** Prove by induction on $a$, $$N(n) = N(a+2)N(n−1−a) + N(a)N(n−2−a) + N(a+1)N(n−3− a)$$
>   for $a > 0$ and $n > a + 3$. (Assume $N(0) = 0$).

Induction on "$a$". :O So lost! :'(

> **b.** Assuming the fact from part (a), prove that
>   $$N(2k) = N(k)N(k) + 2N(k)N(k−2) + N(k−1)N(k−1)$$ and
>   $$N(2k−1) = N(k)N(k) + 2N(k−1)N(k−2)$$
>
> **c.** Find similar formulas for $N(2k+1)$ and $N(2k+2)$ in terms of $N(k)$, $N(k−1)$,
>   and $N(k−2)$.

Comment: Induction has three parts to it. The "base case", the "induction hypothesis", and the "induction step". Start by showing that it is true for $a>0$ first.

Comment: Yep. I have done that. The part which is throwing me off is the Induction on "a" bit. So, if the I.H is that it is true for all cases a' < a, I seem to hit a dead-end. Else, if the I.H. is that it is true for a, and I sit to prove that it is true for a+1 as well, I'm getting no new leads, no ways of combining terms to express in terms of the Function N.

Comment: I see that by susbstituing a=0 you achieve the original function of n. However try this for a =1 which implies n>4. Then choose a=k and this implies n>k+3 and continue. Goodluck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(a.1)** Basis ($a=1$): you assume $n>4$ and:

$$
N(3)N(n-2) + N(1)N(n-3) + N(2)N(n-4) = N(n-2) + N(n-3) + N(n-4)
=N((n-1) - 1) + N((n-1)-3) + N(n-3) = N(n-1) + N(n-3) = N(n)
$$

Obs: you can check manually the case $n=4$ where the induction formula is not guaranteed to work using $N(0)=0$.

**(a.2)** Inductive step: assume the formula works for $a$, and as usual, assume $n>a+3$. We work on $a+1$:

$$
N(a+3)N(n-2-a) + N(a+1)N(n-3-a) + N(a+2)N(n-4-a) = \\ 
=N((a+2)+1)N((n-1-a)-1) + N((a)+1)N((n-2-a)-1) + N((a+1)+1)N((n-3-a)-1)
$$

which we want to show it's still $N(n)$. We can approach it in parts. From the recurrence of the function, we know that $N(n+1) = N(n)+N(n-2)$ and $N(n-1) = N(n)-N(n-3)$. We have 3 product blocks, so let's open up each one:

**1. >** $(N(a+2) + N(a))(N(n-a-1)-N(n-a-4))$.

**2. >** $(N(a) + N(a-2))(N(n-2-a) - N(n-a-5))$.

**3. >** $(N(a+1) + N(a-1))(N(n-3-a)-N(n-a-6))$.

Note that, when you distribute these products, the first term on each of them adds up to $N(n)$ by the induction hypothesis. So, you're left to prove that the sum of the remaining terms is $0$, and believe me, you can. It's pretty gross, so I'm not doing it here (took one A4 page), but multiply them up and use the two recurrence relations I mentioned above and you can check that they actually cancel each other. It's messy, but not hard.

**(b)** Pick $a=k-2$, and let's apply the formula from the previous item:

$$
N(2k) = N(k)N(k+1) + N(k-2)N(k) + N(k-1)N(k-1) = \\
= N(k)(N(k) + N(k-2)) + N(k-2)N(k) + N(k-1)N(k-1) = \\
N(k)N(k) + 2N(k)N(k-2) + N(k-1)N(k-1),
$$
as desired. For the second formula, again, pick $a=k-2$, and the expression yields:

$$
N(2k-1) = N(k)N(2k-2-k+2) + N(k-2)N(2k-1-2-k+2) + N(k-1)N(2k-1-3-k+2) = \\
= N(k)N(k) + 2N(k-1)N(k-2).
$$

**(c)** For $N(2k+1)$, pick $a=k-1$. Applying the formula, we have:
$$
N(2k+1) = N(k+1)N(k+1) + 2N(k-1)N(k) = \\
= (N(k)+N(k-2))^{2} + 2N(k-1)N(k).
$$

Finally, for $N(2k+2)$, note that we have a formula for $N(2k)$. Apply that for $2(k+1)$, and we have:

$$
N(2k+2) = N(2(k+1)) = N(k+1)N(k+1) + 2N(k+1)N(k-1) + N(k)N(k) = \\
=(N(k)+N(k-2))^{2} + 2N(k-1)(N(k) + N(k-2)) + (N(k))^{2}
$$

which are all in terms of $N(k),N(k-1)$ or $N(k-2)$, and you can expand it further if you want.

Comment: Bruh. I owe you one. Big time. If I can request your help one more time, where can I find similar problems like this? I would like to practise and condition my thinking in order to crack such problems in the future.. Any tips? :)